# Upper Bound on injectivity radius of the cover of a closed manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

I am trying to understand the following fact:

Given a compact Riemannian closed 3-manifold $M$ such that there is a surjection $\phi:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow \mathbb Z *\mathbb Z$ with non-trivial kernel then the injectivity radius at every point of the cover of $M$ corresponding to $ker(\phi)$ has an upper bound, i.e. there are no arbitrarily large isometrically embedded balls in the cover.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why the injectivity radius corresponding to $ket\phi$ has an upper bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N$ is a connected Riemannian $n$-manifold which is not diffeomorphic to $R^n$, then the injectivity radius of $M$ is finite (pretty much by the definition), hence, has an upper bound.

As for your question about existence of an upper bound on $InRad(x)$, $x\in N$ (where $N$ is the covering space), it is again a general fact:

Suppose that $N$ is a Riemannian $n$-manifold which admits a cocompact isometric group action and $N$ is not diffeomorphic to $R^n$. Then 
$$
\sup_{x\in N} InRad(x) <\infty. 
$$
This follows from the fact that for every compact $C\subset N$,
$$
\sup_{x\in C} InRad(x) <\infty. 
$$

Comment: What about a fuchsian hyperbolic 3-manifold, if I take points outside the convex core isn't the injectivity radius going to infinity? I understand that unless $M$ is homeomorphic to an open ball the injectivity radius at any given point is finite. Maybe my question was not phrased correctly, I want to understand why $sup_x inj_x <R$.

Comment: Then you should state your definition of injectivity radius of a manifold: It is usually defined as $\inf_{x\in M} InRad(x)$. Are you defining it as the supremum?

Comment: I corrected the question, thanks for pointing it out.